# I have a custom order of string, need to verify that the list is in correct order. List can have multiple occurrence of same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```py
order = ['critical', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'info']

def verify_order(lst):
    order = ['critical','high', 'medium', 'low', 'info']
    position = {item: -1 for item in order}

    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item in order:
            position[item] = i
            
    last_index = -1

    for index in range(len(order) -1):
        if index[item] < position[order[i+1]]:
            return False
    return True


mylist1 = ['high','medium', 'info', 'info']
mylist2 = ['medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high']
```

list1 should return true, while list2 should return false

dont understand why it isnt working

Comment: You should get an error message. What do you not understand about it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can make this simpler by using `itertools.pairwise`:

```
from itertools import pairwise

order = ['critical', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'info']
index = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(order)}

def verify_order(lst):
    for a, b in pairwise(lst):
        if index[a] > index[b]:
            return False
    return True

verify_order(mylist1)
# True
verify_order(mylist2)
# False
```

And that pattern is idiomatic and also has a util, `all`:

```
def verify_order(lst):
    return all(index[a] <= index[b] for a, b in pairwise(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you initialize `position` seems incorrect, it should not depend on `lst`.

You can first compute a dictionary of positions, then check if any position is lower than the maximum preceding one:

```
def verify_order(lst, order=None):
    if not order:
        order = ['critical', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'info']
    position = {item: idx for idx, item in enumerate(order)}
    # {'critical': 0, 'high': 1, 'medium': 2, 'low': 3, 'info': 4}

    max_item = 0
    for item in lst:
        pos = position.get(item, -1) # if non-existing item, fail
        if pos < max_item:
            return False
        max_item = pos
    return True

verify_order(mylist1)
# True

verify_order(mylist2)
# False

verify_order(order)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I got another way without enumerate:

```
def verify_order(lst):
    order = ['critical', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'info']
    i = 1
    while i < len(lst):
        try:
            if lst[i] in order:
                if order.index(lst[i]) < order.index(lst[i - 1]):
                    return False
            i += 1
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True

mylist1 = ['high', 'medium', 'info', 'info']
mylist2 = ['medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high']
mylist3 = ['x', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high']

verify_order(mylist1)
verify_order(mylist2)
verify_order(mylist3)
```

Which will have the result True, False, False

Comment: What would be the advantage of not using `enumerate`? Here you make the solution quadratic as you have to search in the whole list again for each item (`lst.index`). `enumerate` and a dictionary enable to have a `O(n)` solution.

Comment: Agree @mozway, enumerate works better.